# How to throw objects from one .ts to another .ts

Tags: typescript, constructor

I have an API call on numberOne.ts and i need to throw the response to numberTwo.ts.

I'm trying to throw the API response of numberOne.ts to numberTwo.ts and I have no Idea how to do that, I checked some videos regarding constructors but to no avail.

```
getDealStatusInfo() {
            var statusRes
            var dealid = 111;
            DealApiControllers.GetDealStatus(dealid,
                (response) => {
                    statusRes = response;
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                });

        }
```

I need to use the response on numberTwo.ts

Comment: Do you want the second .ts file to react as soon as `response` is available? you may have to look at `pub-sub` (publish - subscribe) mechanisms

Comment: No I do not need the second .ts to react immediately I just need the response to be ready for my method, since I am using knockout.js promise is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return a response and call getDealStatusInfo() from 
numberTwo.ts

numberOne.ts:

```
export function getDealStatusInfo() {
            var statusRes
            var dealid = 111;
            DealApiControllers.GetDealStatus(dealid,
                (response) => {
                    return response;
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                });

        }
```

numberTwo.ts:

```
import {getDealStatusInfo} from "./your numberOne.ts file path"
status = getDealStatusInfo()
```